# When storing large JSON files it more efficient to store them in a database or as a file on a server?

Tags: php, mysql

My reason for asking is I'm thinking of building a component-based CMS app (kind of) and building said components as a JSON object from drag-and-drop (again kind of).

Thinking of a 1000 lines JSON object here with potentially 1m+ records. I'd like to know:

A. Which would be a more efficient way to store them

B. Any reason not to do one or the other

Comment: Way too little info to give a proper answer. How will you retrieve the data? Will you need to search for data on some criteria, or just retrieve a specific "file"? Will you need to order the data, consolidate (ie. Average, sum, min/max, etc.) it or otherwise manipulate the data or meta data? As for efficiency, if you're referring to disk space, then the file system will use less space. If you're referring to processor load, then it's back to the questions above.

Comment: Why store as JSON? Store as data in database rows and convert to JSON when you retrieve it if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `blob` objects quite well in a DBMS like MySQL, but expect problems when you look at distributing your database across multiple servers and data centers. That's a lot of traffic and latency doing synchronisation.

Could you not deploy the files on a SAN (storage area network) and have a file schema record in the database for the location? You could do fast caching and RAID architectures on the SAN to drive down latency.

Comment: I figured it might be more down to the architecture in the end.  Thanks for clarifying